# VBA xlUp Function

Tags: excel, vba

During counting blank cells I have an issue due to xlUp.That formula range is working only the cell till that there is a value.For instance let assume that
my range is K9:K208 and I have a 155 blank cells. But if there is any value on K205 than it is count as 152 even if has to be 155.How can I handle this issue?

```
Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A4") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K9:K" & lLastRow), "")
End Sub
```

Comment: You've provided no explanation as to why row 208 is supposed to be the last row.

Comment: I try to shared a screenshot but it did not work.Let me explain. Because there is also datas after K205. K columns contain a data validation and K205 is "OK". After the cells K205 is still in progress and that therefore that 3 cells is blank.When I try to ctrl+down it only takes the range till the last nonblank cell.I am thinking that might be reason but I could not able to resolved.

Comment: So why aren't you choosing the column with *'datas after K205'* to assign a 'last row'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate method of locating a 'last row' across many columns.

```
dim lastRow as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = .cells.find("*", after:=.cells(1), _
                     searchorder:=xlbyrows, searchdirection:=xlprevious).row
    .Range("A4") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("K9:K" & lastRow), "")
end with
```

Comment: May I ask you one thing, when I filter than columns formula is not working properly. Is there any chance to handle this as well?

Comment: Typically SUBTOTAL or AGGREGATE is used to discard hidden rows from a count.

Answer (score 1):

`xlUp` is for determining first non-blank cell upwards from starting cell, so `Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp)` will start looking from last row in column `K` upwards. In your case that will be K208 - that is how you should determine last row (`Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row`).

Having `lastRow=208` you can loop starting from 9th row in `K` column (`K9`), like
`For i = 9 To lastRow` and count all blank cells - this will guarantee that you won't miss anything :)

Here's code to get you started:

```
Sub CountBlanks()
Dim i, lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 9 To lastRow
    'check if cell is blank and do any other operations
Next
End Sub
```